# How to indicate in Kotlin that an interface can only be implemented by a data class?

Tags: android, kotlin

### Problem description

I am creating some abstractions for the entities of my application written in kotlin and I would like to indicate that a certain interface can only be implemented by `data class` types. In case the interface is implemented by any other entity than a `data class`, lint should indicate a warning saying that this interface should only be implemented by `data class`, preventing the program from running. Is there a way to do this in kotlin?

### My code

#### Interface

```kotlin
interface UiData // Can only be implemented by data classes
```

#### Success case

In this case `OnboardUiData` is a `data class`, so the program should not throw any kind of error if executed.

```kotlin
data class OnboardUiData(
    val age: Int,
    val height: Float,
    val weight: Float,
    val gender: String
) : UiData // implements ok, OnboardUiData is a data class
```

#### Error case (program must not allow execution)

In this case `OnboardUiData` is not a `data class`, so the program should issue a warning that `OnboardUiData` is not a `data class` and prevent execution if that happens.

```kotlin
class OnboardUiData(
    val age: Int,
    val height: Float,
    val weight: Float,
    val gender: String
) : UiData // implementation fails, OnboardUiData is not a data class
```

Comment: I do not believe that there is a way to do this, short of writing your own Lint rule. What is it *specifically* about a `data class`  that you need? After all, a `data class` is not magic, and anything that a `data class` gives you can be implemented in other ways.

Comment: Hello @CommonsWare, thank you for proposing to discuss the matter. I need the `data class` more for a semantic reason, because it is used for when we want to encapsulate data and modify it through the `copy` method, which would be ideal for storing the ui data of a screen, for example .

Comment: OK, but a non-`data class` can have a `copy()` function that works just like the one on a `data class`.

Comment: I agree, but then I lose the semantics of kotlin that proposes to use the `data class` type for when we want to store a set of values.

Comment: Doesn't seem like something that needs to be enforced unless your team is full of a rotating roster of day-one Kotlin users.

Comment: I could not do this lint and the whole application would still work fine, but I would like to create it to indicate that if a person is implementing this interface in something other than a `data class` they are probably doing something wrong. For example, when using the `inner interface` signature, an internal kotlin lint is triggered: "Modifier 'inner' is not applicable to 'interface'"

Comment: In addition to the comments of the others here: the distinction should not be data class vs class, it should be specific data classes (in your case UI-related) vs other data classes & classes. I'm pretty sure you won't use data classes in your applications only for the UI.